# How to call a Class inside a package from html form

Tags: java, html, servlets, netbeans

Im trying to put my `doLogin.java` class (servlet) inside a package named `LoginSession` but I can't call this class from my form `<form name="logForm" action="LoginSession/doLogin" method="POST">`, it will raise a server error on source not being found.

When I put the class inside the default package I can call it without any problem just by modifying the action this way `<form name="logForm" action="doLogin" method="POST">` but I know putting classes directly into the default package is a very bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to it as `LoginSession.doLogin`, using the fully-qualified class name.

Alternatively, you can define a [servlet-mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/webapp/configureservlet.html) and associate a url-pattern with meaningful shortnames to refer to the servlet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the `LoginSession.doLogin` did not work, I'll try with the servlet-mapping later, although I do think it's kind of an overkill, there must be a way to simply call a class inside my package.

Comment: Can you confirm if `doLogin.class` is present in `WEB-INF/classes/LoginSession` folder? Also, I hope you included `package LoginSession;` in you `doLogin.java`.

Comment: There is nothing inside my `WEB-INF/` folder, which I don't know what it means because im calling my class in the default package without any problem. Also the `package LoginSession` line is already inside the doLogin.java

Comment: Why are you not trying servlet mapping?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML Page

```
<form action = "com.Demo">
```

In `Dmo.java` file included in com package

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Demo</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.Demo</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/com.Demo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```